# HTML div with absolute position tries to wrap the text. Can I avoid it, without using white space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a set of divs with position = absolute, and they can be positioned across the screen.

If the content of any div doesn't fit on the screen, the browser wraps the text into multiple lines and attempt to fit inside the window.

However, I dont want the browser to do that, It should instead hide the content.

http://jsbin.com/welcome/35835/edit/

Edit:

you may think of it as a div on a page with absolute positioning. and

1) the user can drag the div around

2) user can manually change the width of the div( there is a stretch box widget, which the user can use)..

So the problem is when the user is dragging the div around near the edges of the screen, the text should hide and not wrap if it goes out of the window. Hope this explains better

As shown in the example, block 2 shown is what I want.

So, lets say the width of the div is 100px, and the left position of the CSS style is (screen width - 50), then the rest of the text should hide.

Solution 1: white-space:nowrap. Cant use this, since this is a flexible width UI where user can change the width of the div if they want.

Solution 2: If I set the width of the div, explicitly to a number, it works fine.

But not a optimal solution, as then here I will always have to calculate the width for all divs at the time of rendering.

Is there a more optimal solution, which can make the browser not try to fit the text into the screen.

Comment: If relying on CSS3 isn't an issue you could try `text-wrap:none;`

Comment: @Nw167 isn't that the same as white-space in a way and it is not supported in major browsers

Comment: if user can set the width then why not let them set the widget at the start. you can default to some arbitrary width (percent width maybe) and the user can set their own when the widget initializes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell what you're asking. But I think you can use

```
{
  height: 1.2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

To hide the content that is longer than the one line you support

http://jsfiddle.net/MXXDC/2/

Comment: @sbr  It'd be better if you described what is wrong with what I did. That description is way too confusing and I'm not willing to try and make sense of it again.

Comment: this reason for the above comment is because we can have the ability to drag the div around.

Comment: Make it whatever you want, it will still work, won't it? Here's an example where I use left and make them 0, 10, 20. http://jsfiddle.net/MXXDC/19/

Comment: Thanks.The only thing is :If the whole word doesn't fit in, it hides the word leaving a white space close to the edge. Also, height value will have to set at the run time, based on the font of the text.

Comment: @sbr Both points are very true. For the height to be more flexible with font sizes, just use `em`. http://jsfiddle.net/MXXDC/21/ I don't know of a way to address the white space problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MXXDC/8/) what you want? (second item)

I wrapped the inner text in a very long div and applied `overflow:hidden` to it's parent.

Comment: Thanks. adding borders helped. But here again we still set the width of the wrapper explicitly.

Comment: Yes but it just has to be overly huge to accommodate all the possibilities... unless you think about putting in a book in the div :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Last fiddle contains white-space and you said in the question that you didn't want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you put them all inside a huge (e.g. 5k px * 5k px absolute positioned div you should see the expected effect: http://jsbin.com/welcome/35862/edit

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the exact use case of the widget so I am not 100% sure on what it can have and not have. I have an idea, maybe it will be useful - setting width to a % might help, something like this

```
.block2{
    left: 50%;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

you can set this in the css to avoid calculation with js, but like I said I am not sure of how this is used so this might not work but it might give you some ideas

Comment: you may think of it as a div on a page with absolute positioning. and 1) the user can drag the div around 2) manually change the width of the div( there is a stretch box widget, which the user can use).. So the problem is when the user is dragging the div around near the edges of the screen, the text should hide and not wrap if it goes out of the window. Hope this explains better.